# Does This Rock Contain A Fossil?

Tags: palaeontology, fossil

A couple of months ago I came across a rock which has suspicious insertions in it. It was found in southern Spain, more specificaly hiking near Zahara de la Sierra (coordinates are provided: 36.830427, -5.416054). I am curious if it could contain some sort of fossil as some of the structures are bone-ish. The rock is 40 x 40 x 10 cm (16 x 16 x 4 inches) in volume and weighs around 10 kg (22 lb) Thank you beforehand[image]

[image]

Comment: There seem to be inclusions in a sedimentary rock, but without a clearer picture, there's no hope of identifying anything. Could you provide a few other angles including the underside - in as high resolution as possible.

Comment: think of uploading some close ups to fossil id forums

Comment: Seconding @JiminyCricket. You can't tell with this quality of photo - would need closer up of the "fossil" bits and some different angles; but look like inclusions or intrusions of some sort to me.

Comment: the stuff in the upper center of the photo is the only stuff that could possibly be a fossil, so providing a close up of that might be enough.

Comment: I added an extra picture I had in my gallery, but soon you'll get some more closeups and different angle shots. Sorry!